# Accessing mass information from a belongs_to association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have the following models:

```
class Parcel < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :parcel_data
  # has attribute "parcel_name", which is a string
end

class ParcelData < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :parcels
  # has attribute "parcel_id" which is an integer
  # has attribute "price" which is an integer
  # has attribute "description" which is a string
end
```

I want to select a group of `Parcels`, and work with the related prices, or descriptions.

Right now, I do something like this:

```
parcs = Parcel.where("id < ?",30)
description_array = Array.new
price_sum = 0

parcs.each do |p|
    description_array.push(p.parcel_data.description)
    price_sum += p.parcel_data.price
end
```

Is there a better way to build the "description_array" array, or the "price_sum" value?

I know this doesn't work, but something like:

```
price_sum = parcs.parcel_data.sum(:price)
description_array = parcls.parcel_data.pluck(:description)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I enjoy point free style, I would consider:

```
# the Enumerable#sum used here is Rails, not Ruby
price_sum = parcels.map(&:parcel_data).compact.sum(&:price)
# plain old Ruby alternative, no Enumerable#sum
price_sum = parcels.map(&:parcel_data).compact.map(&:price).reduce(:+)

description_array = parcels.map(&:parcel_data).compact.map(&:description)
```

The `Array#compact` is just in case you have parcels without data: if your association is mandatory, you may not need it.

Eager loading for large datasets, if you're not doing it already, may save you spam in console and load on server. E.g., one way: `Parcel.where("id < ?", 30).includes(:parcel_data)`

Comment: Awesome.  That's a neat way to do it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Learning to use Ruby's enumerable methods will go a long way in helping you simplify code like this

```
parcs = Parcel.where("id < ?",30)
descriptions = parcs.map {|p| p.parcel_data.description }
total_price = parcs.inject(0) {|sum, p| sum + p.parcel_data.price }
```

[`map` documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-map)

[`inject` documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject)